# No idea how to get server address in subnetwork UDP sockets c

Tags: c, network-programming, udp, broadcast

I have a question:

Is there any way and if there is how I can discover server address via broadcasts from client's point of view?

I read almost everything on the Internet and there is no information how I can discover server address without knowing its name (gethostbyname()). I need to create a client-server application with UDP where a Server sends broadcast and clients are supposed to discover it and send some text back to it.

As far as I know the client needs to create a socket then get host (server) address by gethostbyname() in order to have an address on which it could recvfrom() and then perform i.e. sendto().

Basically server starts only with port (command line parameter) on which creates its socket and bind() and client is also started with only port (command line parameter) and is supposed to discover server address via broadcasts. This is what I have so far:

SERVER:

```
   struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int socketfd,t=1;
    socketfd = make_socket(PF_INET,type);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,&t, sizeof(t))) ERR("setsockopt");
    if(bind(socketfd,(struct sockaddr*) &addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0)  ERR("bind");
```

Then I would like to broadcast it to everywhere in the subnetwork from server but dunno why:(

CLIENT:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct hostent *hostinfo;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons (port);
    hostinfo = gethostbyname(address);
    if(hostinfo == NULL)HERR("gethostbyname");
    addr.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr*) hostinfo->h_addr;
```

Here I would like to receive in some way what server broadcasted and send back some text.

EDIT:
I would do that by:

```
int fd;
struct sockaddr_in addr;

fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

char buf[TEXT_SIZE];
socklen_t size=sizeof(addr);

recvfrom(fd, (char *)buf, sizeof(char[FILE_SIZE]), 0, &addr, &size);
```

But how do I set server to broadcast it so that client from the above code could receive it? I always sent it by:

```
sendto(fd, (char *)some_buffer, sizeof(some_buffer), 0, &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

But my server cannot discover clients `addr` because it has to first send the broadcast to all clients. So I cannot fill `addr` here because it is not set yet. Is there any way that server would first broadcast the message without knowing clients address? Server only creates a socket binds it and then needs to immediately broadcast some text. Thank you for replies.

Comment: Use recvfrom th receive frames and get the sender address.

Comment: maybe this can help> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017803/listening-to-a-udp-broadcast

Comment: "*I read almost everything on the Internet ...*" WHOW! ;-)

Comment: Did you do the suggested changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. I assume server is sending broadcast and client hangs on `recvfrom`, I hope you know how to fix this, thank you.

**SERVER:**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define ERR(source) (perror(source),\
             fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__),\
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE))

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int port = atoi(argv[1]);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int server_socket, t = 1;
    socklen_t size = sizeof(addr);

    server_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (setsockopt(server_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST ,&t, sizeof(t)))
        ERR("setsockopt");

    if(bind(server_socket,(struct sockaddr*) &addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0) 
        ERR("bind");

    char buf[12] = "FromServer";

    /* I assume here I broadcast message assuming I set all attributes properly */
    if(sendto(server_socket, buf, sizeof(char[12]), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("problem");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Sent to client: %s \n", buf);

    sleep(2);

    if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(server_socket))<0)
        ERR("close");

    printf("\n\n----------------- Server [%d] terminated. -----------------  \n", getpid());    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**CLIENT:**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define BACKLOG 10
#define ERR(source) (perror(source),\
             fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__),\
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE))
#define HERR(source) (fprintf(stderr,"%s(%d) at %s:%d\n",source,h_errno,__FILE__,__LINE__),\
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE))

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int client_socket;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* client port */
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);

    client_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    char data[12];

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t size = sizeof(addr);

    /* Here I would like to receive server broadcast (i.e. some text) but it hangs for ever */
    if(recvfrom(client_socket, (char *)data, sizeof(char[12]), 0, &addr, &size) < 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Received from server: %s \n", data);

    if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(client_socket))<0)
        ERR("close");

    printf("\n\n----------------- Client [%d] terminated. -----------------  \n", getpid());    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I added my comments in the section of my response.

Comment: I see the code, please change the type of port to short int. Both in the client and server. In the client, bind the socket client_socket to the port and address, define another struct sockaddr_in (different from addr), zero it, and set the corresponding values: sin_family, sin_addr, sin_port ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion in how you are tackling the problem.

gethostbyname will use the resolver to lookup the IP address based on the name provided. So you will need to provide the server name and have the mapping somewhere: it could be the corresponding entry in hosts file or a A (or AAAA) record in a DNS server.

But from your problem description, it seems you don't want to use gethostbyname to obtain the server IP address.

If the server is broadcasting UDP datagrams and your client knows the port to which it is braodcasting, the client can read the UDP datagram and obtain the source address.

BTW, the server code you show is not sending broadcast.

This looks as an exercise for a networking course.

Comment: Thank you for your response.'If the server is broadcasting UDP datagrams and your client knows the port to which it is braodcasting, the client can read the UDP datagram and obtain the source address.' How would I read those broadcasts in a client knowing this port to which server is broadcasting to? Because when I just try recvfrom (in a client) to get the address of the server, the client hangs for ever. In a client I create a socket and immediately after that try recvfrom and the client hangs..

Comment: You would help me more if you copy the whole code for the client. fI you have the code as you showed in your post, that won't work. You are missing some fields of addr there. Please, could you copy your code correctly instead of various separate snippets?

Comment: @Christopher_Programmer_Wannabe, I see the code, please change the type of port to short int.

Comment: @Christopher_Programmer_Wannabe, I see the code, please change the type of port to short int. Both in the client and server. In the client, bind the socket client_socket to the port and address, define another struct sockaddr_in (different from addr), zero it, and set the corresponding values: sin_family, sin_addr, sin_port ...